# FileHelpers.dll not ignoring private fields?

Tags: .net, filehelpers

I've used the FileHelpers.dll library found [here](http://www.filehelpers.com/) in the past with success. In this specific case, this time around last year, I was able to make the class generate some flat files. For some reason, a full year later, I come back to my old project, make some modifications and now it won't work. I'm trying to use FixedLengthRecord to write some data to a file, but now it complains that not all my fields have the FixedField attribute. I double, triple, quadruple checked and all my public fields have the required attribute. After commenting all of my methods and properties I realized that it was complaining about some private fields I use to back some of the class' properties. I had to apply a Ignore attribute on these private fields for it to work.

My question is, what could I have possibly done this time around for it to behave in this manner? Last year the exact same class definitions worked like a charm and it ignored all of my private fields. I'm using VS2008 and FileHelpers.dll version 2.0.0.0 (same version I used last year). I tried searching the docs and reading some of the source code, but I can't seem to find anything related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in fact the library includes all the fields (public or private) you must to explicity exclude them out with `[FieldHidden]` attribute.

You can download the last stable version from the home page:

[www.filehelpers.net](http://www.filehelpers.net)

Comment: I'm confused though, how did I manage to make this work last year without the explicit ignores? I'm gonna dig into that source code to make sure I didn't add those properties/backing fields after the fact. Also, I'm flattered to receive a reply from the library's own author, thanks a lot :).

Comment: Seems I just wasted a full day trying to fix this "bug". Going back to my git log shows clearly that I hadn't added the properties or backing fields when I used it last year. I are dumb.

Comment: Glad to help :) And you are correct that we dont have that behavior clearly documented, thanks for the feedback

Comment: Thanks but [FieldIgnored] is obsolete, and is replaced by [FieldHidden]. Perhaps OP @MarcosMeli could update the original answer to reflect API changes from FileHelpers library.